# Synchronized method in Java monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, monitor

I am currently learning the use of monitor in Java, but i do not know how the synchronized methods work.

I understand that while one thread is inside a synchronized method, another thread cannot be inside a synchronized method and that sleep doesn't take off the monitor's own ownership.

So i tried to write a code to test that

```
import java.util.Random;
public class ex3 extends Thread {

private static int nbA=0;
private static int nbB=0;
public static final Random rand = new Random();

public void run(){
    while(true){
        System.out.println(nbA+" "+nbB);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(500));
        }catch (Exception e ){e.printStackTrace();}
        if (rand.nextBoolean()){
            try {
                A();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }else{
            try {
                B();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void A() throws InterruptedException{
    nbA++;
    Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(500));
    nbA--;
}

public synchronized void B() throws InterruptedException{   
    nbB++;
    Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(500));
    nbB--;
}

public static void main(String[] argv){
    new ex3().start();
    new ex3().start();
    new ex3().start();
}
}
```

I believed it was impossible that  nbA or nbB be superior to 1 or that nbB and nbA  are both >0   but it's happening

What do I misunderstand ?

Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're synchronizing on different objects: a `synchronized` non-static method synchronizes on `this`, so each of the `new ex3()` instances effectively works like it's not synchronized.

A synchronized instance method is exactly equivalent to this:

```
public void A() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // The body.
    }
}
```

Either make the synchronized methods `static`, or explicitly synchronize on the class (or something other shared object):

```
public void A() throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized (ex3.class) {
        nbA++;
        Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(500));
        nbA--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that while one thread is inside a synchronized method, another thread cannot be inside a synchronized method

Wrong. It cannot be inside a synchronized method *synchronized on the same object.* It can be inside any other synchronized method, or the same method synchronized on a different object, as here.

> and that sleep doesn't take off the monitor's own ownership.

Correct.

NB Per Brinch Hansen doesn't consider Java to have monitors, and he invented them.